# How to move data in sheet1 to sheet2 in excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I am writing contents to an excel file through c#. I am having 4 columns and many rows in excel. When the application runs, I need to check if whether data is present in sheet1, then it should be moved to sheet2. If sheet2 also contains data, then it should be appended with sheet2 data. I am using interop dll for accessing excel. I have done with writing contents, but how I can move it programmatically? This is what I tried.

```
  Excel.Workbook xlwb;
  Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Worksheet xlssheet1;
  Excel.Worksheet xlssheet2; 
 xlwb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing,
                                    objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing);
            int rowIndex = 2; int colIndex = 1;
            if (excelApp.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] != null)
            {
                xlssheet1 = (Worksheet)xlwb.Worksheets[1];
                xlssheet2 = (Worksheet)xlwb.Worksheets[2];

                xlwb.Sheets.Move(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, xlssheet2);
                xlwb.Save();                

            }
```

Comment: I used InterOp in the past and found it very troublesome. If you know you won't deal with old excel files, I suggest you take a look at the [OpenXML library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) (or the simplified 3rd party [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd define a function to find out the last used row of a worksheet:

```
private int LastUsedRow(Excel.Worksheet aSheet)
{
    object hmissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    string usedAddress = aSheet.UsedRange.get_Address(hmissing, hmissing, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, hmissing, hmissing);
    return int.Parse(usedAddress.Substring(usedAddress.LastIndexOf('$') + 1));
}
```

Then your code can iteratively copy the cells from one worksheet to the other in this way:

```
Excel.Workbook xlwb;
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Worksheet xlssheet1;
Excel.Worksheet xlssheet2; 
xlwb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing, objMissing);
xlssheet1 = (Worksheet)xlwb.Worksheets[1];
xlssheet2 = (Worksheet)xlwb.Worksheets[2];
int lastRow1 = LastUsedRow(xlssheet1);
int lastRow2 = LastUsedRow(xlssheet2);
int curRow = lastRow2 + 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= lastRow1; i++)
{
    object toCopy = xlsheet1.getRange("A"+i, "D" + i).get_Value(null);
    xlsheet2.getRange("A"+curRow, "D" + curRow).set_Value(null, toCopy);
    curRow++;
}
xlwb.Save();
```

Comment: @Baruchelli : Hi, This works well. Just one update, we need to increment curRow by 1. Else only one value will be copied to sheet2. Inside for loop: if (i > 1)
                    curRow = curRow + 1;. Thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to "Move" the data, move it manually:

1. Copy the values over
2. Ensure the copies worked
3. Make the original cell blanks
4. Save

Comment: I cannot move manually. Because it may contain many rows and its a daily task

Comment: Went I said "Manually" I really meant programmatically. As in, if you can't find a "Move" function, just copy + make the original cell blanks (through code). It will have the same effect. Your original question said "I can write cells, but how to move them" - also notice that the answer you chose doesn't actually move the values, it copies them over.